# How to disable a submit button with vanilla javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I don't want the submit button to be enabled if the default values of the drop-downs are present.

[image]

This is the portion of my code which relates to my problem:

```
  function checkSelect(select) {
    if (select.value == '-- select an option --') submit.disabled = true;
    else submit.disabled = false;
  }

  (function() {
    if (checkSelect(starting)) {
      starting.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        startingEventVal = returnAirPort(e.srcElement.value);
        console.log('startingEventVal', startingEventVal);
      });
    }
    if (checkSelect(destination)) {
      starting.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        startingEventVal = returnAirPort(e.srcElement.value);
        console.log('startingEventVal', startingEventVal);
      });
    }
  })();
```

And this is all of my code:

```
(function() {
  var starting = document.getElementById('starting'),
    destination = document.getElementById('destination'),
    submit = document.getElementById('submit'),
    airportNames = Object.keys(IntentMedia.Airports.airport_distances()),
    startingEventVal,
    destinationEventVal;

  function appendToUL(ul, element) {
    var optionEL = document.createElement('option');
    optionEL.text = element;
    optionEL.value = element;
    return ul.appendChild(optionEL);
  }

  function returnAirPort(airport) {
    return airport;
  }

  function checkSelect(select) {
    if (select.value == '-- select an option --') submit.disabled = true;
    else submit.disabled = false;
  }

  airportNames.forEach(function(element) {
    appendToUL(starting, element);
    appendToUL(destination, element);
  });

  (function() {
    if (checkSelect(starting)) {
      starting.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        startingEventVal = returnAirPort(e.srcElement.value);
        console.log('startingEventVal', startingEventVal);
      });
    }
    if (checkSelect(destination)) {
      starting.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        startingEventVal = returnAirPort(e.srcElement.value);
        console.log('startingEventVal', startingEventVal);
      });
    }
  })();

  submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var distance = IntentMedia.Distances.distance_between_airports(startingEventVal, destinationEventVal);
    console.log('distance', distance);

    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = distance;
  });
})();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what you can do is disable the button by default, on selection of destination,you can check whether departing is selected or not, if both are selected enable the button

Comment: Your problem is here: "select.value == '-- select an option --'", this is not the value of the drop down, this is the selected options' text

Comment: It would help to have the HTML code also, so we can see what the select field values are.

Comment: I'm actually generating them dynamically with `airportNames = Object.keys(IntentMedia.Airports.airport_distances())
` and then doing `function appendToUL(ul, element) {
    var optionEL = document.createElement('option');
    optionEL.text = element;
    optionEL.value = element;
    return ul.appendChild(optionEL);
  }
  airportNames.forEach(function(element) {
    appendToUL(starting, element);
    appendToUL(destination, element);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Fix this function:

```
//This is wrong because select.value refers to the value property of the select
//and you are comparing that to the selected option's text
function checkSelect(select) {
    if (select.value == '-- select an option --') submit.disabled = true;
    else submit.disabled = false;
  }
```

Change it to this:

```
//Compare the selected option's text to see if it equals the default option text
function checkSelect(select) {
    if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].text == '-- select an option --') submit.disabled = true;
    else submit.disabled = false;
  }
```

Comment: I think this may be premature, if there isn't a different value declared, the option text is also the option value.

Comment: @Devon what kind of crazy world do we live in when options have no value?? :P

Comment: They always have a value, but the value doesn't have to be declared.  It's pretty common to write things like `<option>Value</option>`

Comment: @Devon I was just joking.

Answer (score 0):

in the click event, try checking for the values of the inputs in an if statement and doing:

```
return;
```

to exit the function if they are the default values